# How to use AsyncNotifierProvider in Controller with Riverpod in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

Basically what I am trying to do is the following:

When navigating to a users profile page, the user's basic information (image, name, etc.) should be fetched. Also based on the selected index of the TabView other information should be fetched like events and friendships.

The page looks like this:

[image: profile page]

So far I created providers for controllers like this:

```
@riverpod
class ChangePasswordController extends _$ChangePasswordController {

  @override
  FutureOr<void> build() { }

  Future<bool> changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() => _changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword));
    return !state.hasError;
  }

  void forgotPassword(BuildContext context) {
    context.navigateToForgotPasswordPage();
  }

  Future<void> _changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) async {
    return await ref.read(changePasswordProvider).call(Params(oldPassword: oldPassword, newPassword: newPassword));
  }
}
```

to use them in e.g. auth pages like this:

```
class ChangePasswordPage extends StatefulHookConsumerWidget {

  const ChangePasswordPage({ super.key });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ChangePasswordPage> createState() => _ChangePasswordPageState();
}

class _ChangePasswordPageState extends ConsumerState<ChangePasswordPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final state = ref.watch(changePasswordControllerProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: _forgotPassword,
              child: ...
            )
          ),
          CustomButton(
            onPressed: _changePassword,
            title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.change_password_submit_button_title,
            isLoading: state.isLoading
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }

  Future<void> _changePassword() async {
    final controller = ref.read(changePasswordControllerProvider.notifier);
    final bool success = await controller.changePassword(_oldPasswordController.text, _newPasswordController.text);

    if (success && context.mounted) {
      context.pop();
    }
  }

  void _forgotPassword() {
    final controller = ref.read(changePasswordControllerProvider.notifier);
    controller.forgotPassword(context);
  }
}
```

I created a FamilyAsyncNotifier for the user's basic information, because I want to be able to also update certain information without having to fetch again:

```
class AsyncFullUserNotifier extends FamilyAsyncNotifier<FullUserModel?, String> {

  @override
  Future<FullUserModel?> build(String arg) async {
    return _fetchFullUser(arg);
  }

  Future<FullUserModel?> _fetchFullUser(String userId) async {
    return await DatabaseService.instance.getFullUserById(userId);
  }
}

final profileUserProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.family<AsyncFullUserNotifier, FullUserModel?, String>(() => AsyncFullUserNotifier());
```

I also did this for the events- and friendships tabs.

Now what I don't understand is how to use these providers correctly. I thought about creating a controller for the ProfilePage and somehow add the other providers in there, but do not know the best practice to do so.

The User, events and friendships should be able to have separate states like loading, error etc.

So the controller should be able to handle the fetching, but also like the AuthController do simple other tasks like navigating when pressing a button.